# Proving that $\lim_{ (x,y) \to (1,2) } (3x^2+y)=5$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I can't find the sequence to solve the limit in two variables by the definition
$$\lim_{ (x,y) \to (1,2) } (3x^2+y)=5$$

Comment: don't be around here $|3x^2+y-5|\leq |3(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2|$

Comment: $\frac{\epsilon}{4} =\delta $ ??

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're asking for a proof that $\lim_{(x, y) \to (1, 2)} 3x^2 + y = 5$ using sequences; that is, proving that for any sequence $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \ldots$ converging to $(1, 2)$, the sequence $3x_1^2 + y_1, 3x_2^2 + y_2, \ldots$ converges to $5$.

Well, note that if $(x_n, y_n)$ converges to $(1, 2)$ as $n \to \infty$, $x_n$ and $y_n$ must converge to $1$ and $2$ respectively, as $n \to \infty$. Since the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 3x^2$ is continuous, the sequence $3x_1^2, 3x_2^2, 3x_3^2, \ldots$ converges to $3(1)^2 = 3$. Furthermore, note that the sequence $y_1, y_2, y_3, \ldots$ converges to $2$. Thus, the sequence $3x_1^2 + y_1, 3x_2^2 + y_2, 3x_3^2 + y_3, \ldots$ converges, and we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} 3x_n^2 + y_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} 3x_n^2 + \lim_{n\to\infty} y_n = 3 + 2 = 5$$ by limit laws.

Comment: Proof for definition $\epsilon$, $\delta$

Answer (score -1):

Using the definition of limits, we must show that, given $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a $\delta > 0$
such that
$|x
2 + 2y − 5| < \epsilon$ when 0 < |x − 1| < δ and 0 < |y − 2| < δ. If 0 < |x − 1| < δ and
0 < |y − 2| < δ, then
1 − δ < x < 1 + δ
and
2 − δ < y < 2 + δ
excluding x = 1 and y = 2. Thus,
1 − 2δ + δ
2 < x2 < 1 + 2δ + δ
2
and
4 − 2δ < 2y < 4 + 2δ.
Adding
5 − 4δ + δ
2 < x2 + 2y < 5 + 4δ + δ
2
or
−4δ + δ
2 < x2 + 2y − 5 < 4δ + δ
2
.
If δ ≤ 1, it follows that
−5δ < x2 + 2y − 5 < 5δ
i.e., |x
2 + 2y −5| < 5δ whenever 0 < |x−1| < δ and 0 < |y −2| < δ. Choosing 5δ = ε i.e., δ =
ε
5
or
δ = 1 which ever is smaller, it follows that |x
2 +2y−5| < ε when 0 < |x−1| < δ and 0 < |y−2| < δ
i.e., lim
(x,y)→(1,2)
x
2 + 2y = 5.

Comment: Please use mathjax to typeset formula or your answer may attract close votes.